# Do I have to downgrade to Node 9 in order to run my angular 6 application in Windows 10?

Tags: node.js, windows-10, python-2.x, angular-cli-v6

After Window 10 upgrade I am unable to run my Angular 6 application. It was working fine with Windows 7, node 10, Python3 setup. After upgrade its failing.

Any help highly appreciated. Do I have to downgrade to Node 9.x?

```
My setup: Angular CLI: 6.2.1 / Node: 10.0.0 / OS: win32 x64 / npm: 6.4.1 /
Editor: VS code / Python: 3.6.3
```

Now when am running "npm start" I am getting Module build failed: Error: `sass-loader` requires `node-sass` >=4.

Tried to install node-sass@latest but its looking for Python2 and I have Python 3.x installed. Now do I have to downgrade to Python 2?

What is the best way to run Angular 6 application with Windows 10 by using Node 10?

This is my understanding: Either I have to downgrade to Node 9.x or have to install Python2 to install node-sass@latest.

Thanks
A

Comment: No, you don't have to. node-sass requirement has nothing to do with Node version. Nothing from what you said suggests that. It's unknown what is the problem, and the question lacks https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . Deleting node_modules and reinstalling it is the first step that should be done by default.

Comment: Be carefull [node.js v9.x.x](https://github.com/nodejs/Release#release-schedule) is #endOfLife status